# Save a workbook without Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enable macro.
I am trying to save it without macro.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

would save it is in the right format ....but the macro are still there.
Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: First make sure that you close the workbook and re-open it. The macros still appear in the editor until the workbook gets re-started. If that does not fix it: Can you please show a full [mcve]? Because according to those lines posted there would be no macro.

Answer (score -1):

Did you put macros in Module code sheet? This button should automatically remove modules, I do not know what happens to `UserClass/UserForms/workbook/worksheet object macros`, did not test.

version: Excel 2013

```
Public Sub saveAsXlsx()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim name As String
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    name = wb.Path & "\test_new.xlsx"
    Call wb.SaveAs(name, xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code saves the "Active" workbook instead of "ThisWorkbook", but beside that: I don't see anything that you do different...